# SVG element can't set height by percentage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

I have this code below that consists of a button which opens up my modal. Inside the modal is a SVG element. The problem is that I'm trying to set the height and width of that element but it doesn't seem to work.

It only works for my width and not the height. When I tried setting the height by px it works, but if I set it by percentage then it doesn't.

I'm not sure why this is happening but I want to set my height by percentage. Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```js
  var graph = {
    "nodes": [{ "id": "Apple", "group": 1 }, { "id": "Cherry", "group": 1 }, { "id": "Tomato", "group": 1 }, { "id": "Chilli", "group": 1 }, { "id": "Red Fruits", "group": 1 }],

    "links": [{ "source": "Apple", "target": "Red Fruits", "value": 10, "type": "A" },
    { "source": "Cherry", "target": "Red Fruits", "value": 10, "type": "A" },
    { "source": "Tomato", "target": "Red Fruits", "value": 10, "type": "A" },
    { "source": "Chilli", "target": "Red Fruits", "value": 10, "type": "A" }]


  };
  var fruits = ["Apple", "Cherry", "Tomato", "Chilli"];
  var color = ["Red Fruits"];

  var colorNodes = graph["nodes"];
  let greyNodes = colorNodes;
  greyNodes.forEach((obj) => {
    if (fruits.includes(obj.id.toString())) obj.group = "1"
  })

  let redNodes = greyNodes;
  redNodes.forEach((obj) => {
    if (color.includes(obj.id.toString())) obj.group = "2"
  })


  var colorLinks = graph["links"];
  let linksArray = colorLinks;
  linksArray.forEach((obj) => {
    if (color.includes(obj.target.toString())) obj.type = "B"
  })

  var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

  var zoom_handler = d3.zoom().on("zoom", zoom_actions);

  var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink().distance(300).id(function (d) {
      return d.id;
    }))
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-300))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

  var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "everything");

  svg.call(zoom_handler)
    .call(zoom_handler.transform, d3.zoomIdentity.translate(100, 100).scale(1));

  var link = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .style("stroke", linkColour)
    .attr("stroke-width", function (d) {
      return Math.sqrt(d.value);
    });

  var nodeGroup = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "nodes");

  var node = nodeGroup.selectAll("circle")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .attr("fill", circleColour)
    .attr("id", function (d) { return d.id })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

  function cleanId(id) { return id.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "_"); }

  node.append("title")
    .text(function (d) { return d.id; });

  node.each(d => {
    nodeGroup.append("text") // Labelling for nodes
      .attr("id", 't_' + cleanId(d.id))
      .text(d.id);
  });

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", function (d) { return d.source.x; })
      .attr("y1", function (d) { return d.source.y; })
      .attr("x2", function (d) { return d.target.x; })
      .attr("y2", function (d) { return d.target.y; });
    node
      .attr("cx", function (d) { return d.x; })
      .attr("cy", function (d) { return d.y; })
      .each(d => { d3.select('#t_' + cleanId(d.id)).attr('x', d.x + 10).attr('y', d.y + 3); });
  };

  simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(graph.links);

  function circleColour(d) {
    if (d.group == "1") {
      return "DimGrey";
    } else if (d.group == "2") {
      return "#81C784";
    }
    else {
      return "blue"
    }
  }

  function linkColour(d) {
    if (d.type == "A") {
      return "DimGrey";
    } else {
      return "SpringGreen";
    }
  }


  function zoom_actions() {
    g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
  }

  function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
  }

  function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
  }

  function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
  }
```

```css
    .modal-posit {
      position: relative;
    }

    .links line {
      stroke: #999;
      stroke-opacity: 0.6;
    }

    .nodes circle {
      stroke: #000;
      stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }

    text {
      font-size: 30px;
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    .modal-lg{
      width: 90%;
      height: 80%;
    }
    .center{
      display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    }
    svg{
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>

  </style>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//#" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="capture">



    <button class="modal-button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2">MODAL BUTTON</button>


    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h2 class="modal-title center">GRAPH</h2>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="center">
            <svg style="width: 90%; height: 90%;"></svg>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<script>


</script>
```

Comment: For the `percentage` height to work, it depends on the height of the parent. So i guess it working correctly only since your parent have less height

Answer (score 0):

> Percentage value defines the width as a percentage of the containing block's width. 
>   If the width of the containing block depends on the width of the element, the resulting layout is undefined.

Set width and height of blocks containing SVG.